# Recursion Question - Java - Minimum number of golf shots

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to calculate the minimum number of shots I need to take based on a given number of club lengths. You can also think of it as the minimum number of coins needed for a given change.

My code is

```
   public static int golf(int holeLength, int[] clubLengths)
   {
   return golf(holeLength, clubLengths, 0);
   }

   public static int golf(int holeLength, int[] clubLengths, int shots)
   {
      if(holeLength==0) 
         shots+=0;
      else if(holeLength<0)
         shots=-1;
      else
      {      
         for(int i = 0; i<clubLengths.length; i++)
         {
            return golf(holeLength-clubLengths[i], clubLengths, shots+1);
         }
      }

      return shots;
   }
```

The issue here is that it only seems to give an answer based on the first number on the array. So for example, if I had {25,50,100} and I wanted to get to 100. Obviously, there is only a minimum of one shot required, yet the program will only calculate it using 25 and say 4. Similarly, if the first number is 21, then it will just give a stackoverflow.

Comment: it does only check the first number because the only instruction in the for loop is the return so at the first iterration it will return and cancel all remaining iterations. You need to rethink your logic (I'm not really sure what you want to achieve with this array)

Comment: My bad after reading it again it becomes clearer. You could try in the for loop, either starting by the biggest value in the array if its ordered and check if its smaller than the holelenght or maybe dont use return and put the result in a temp variable and try it with each iteration in the loop and only return the smallest shots

Comment: I am trying to not use return and instead use an if to compare each number of shots and only store the smallest, yet it doesn't change anything. 
So my new for loop is this
      `for(int i = 0; i<clubLengths.length; i++)
      {
         tempShots += 1+golf(holeLength-clubLengths[i], clubLengths, shots+1);
         if(tempShots<=result)
            result=tempShots;
         
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is happening in your code: when the function runs the first loop, it gets the first element in `clubLengths` and returns right away without going to the next loop. You need to go through each possible clubs to use.

Here is my recursive solution:

1. Go through each club.
2. You can choose to use current club and use it again,
3. Or you can choose to use current club and use next club,
4. Or you can choose not to use current club and use next club.

I can implement this the following way:

```
public static int golf(int holeLength, int[] clubLengths) {
    int[][] dp = int[clubLengths.length()][holeLength+1];
    return golf(holeLength, clubLengths, 0, dp);
}

private static int golf(int holeLength, int[] clubLengths, int ind, int[][] dp) {
    if (holeLength == 0) return 0;
    if (holeLength < 0) return -1;
    if (ind >= clubLengths.length()) return -1;
    if (dp[ind][holeLength] != 0) return dp[ind][holeLength];

    int rec1 = golf(holeLength-clubLengths[ind], clubLengths, ind, dp);
    if (rec1 == -1) rec1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else rec1++;

    int rec2 = golf(holeLength-clubLengths[ind], clubLengths, ind+1, dp);
    if (rec2 == -1) rec2 == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else rec2++;

    int rec3 = golf(holeLength, clubLengths, ind+1, dp);
    if (rec3 == -1) rec3 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int result = Math.min(rec1, rec2);
    result = Math.min(result, rec3);
    if (result == Integer.MAX_VALUE) result = -1;

    dp[ind][holeLength] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Along with recursion, I have also added *dp* to optimize time complexity. As a result, the time complexity of my solution would be **O(k*n)** where k is `holeLength` and n is number of elements in `clubsLengths`. If you do not want *dp* and want just pure recursion, you can just remove all usages of `dp` from above and the code will still work, but slower.

Comment: That seems to work quite well! Thank you, however, the solution looks too advanced for what my professor requires. Is there a way to make a couple of changes to my existing code in order to achieve the same thing? Perhaps you can guide me to the answer?

Comment: @AbdullahShahid Try this: 1. Right before the for-loop put `int result = 0;` 2. Within the for-loop, instead of returning the recursive result, do `result = Math.max(result, ~~recursive call~~)`. 3. Right after the for-loop, `return result;`. See if this make your code work.

Comment: This gives an interesting result, so now instead of relying on the first club length, it relies on the last one. Haha, this recursion stuff is really taking its toll on me lol :(